# SoapUI test runner run as admin

Tags: soapui, test-runner

I created test in soapui and few steps are groovy scripts running some python file. It works fine running via testrunner but I have to run SoapUI as administrator. Now I am trying to run this test from jenkins but it is failing because of the same problem. How can I solve this? Thanks

groovy script to run python

```
def cmdArray2 = ["python", "C:/Users/example.py"] 
def process = new ProcessBuilder(cmdArray2).redirectErrorStream(true).start()
process.inputStream.eachLine {
    log.warn(it)
}
process.waitFor()
return process.exitValue()
```

Jenkins batch command

```
"C:\Program Files\SmartBear\ReadyAPI-2.5.0\bin\testrunner.bat" "-RProject Report" "-EDefault environment" "C:\example\example.xml"
```

Error

```
16:56:07,645 WARN  [log] ERROR: setUpClass (__main__.example)
16:56:07,645 WARN  [log] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
16:56:07,645 WARN  [log] Traceback (most recent call last):
16:56:07,645 WARN  [log]   File "C:/Users/example.py", line 18, in setUpClass
16:56:07,645 WARN  [log]     self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
16:56:07,646 WARN  [log]   File "c:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 151, in __init__
16:56:07,646 WARN  [log]     log_path=log_path)
16:56:07,646 WARN  [log]   File "c:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\service.py", line 44, in __init__
16:56:07,646 WARN  [log]     log_file = open(log_path, "a+") if log_path is not None and log_path != "" else None
16:56:07,646 WARN  [log] PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'geckodriver.log'
16:56:07,646 WARN  [log] 
16:56:07,646 WARN  [log] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
16:56:07,646 WARN  [log] Ran 0 tests in 0.002s
16:56:07,647 WARN  [log] 
16:56:07,647 WARN  [log] FAILED (errors=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the BAT file as Admin and you can change as below

`runas /user:Administrator "C:\Program Files\SmartBear\ReadyAPI-2.5.0\bin\testrunner.bat" "-RProject Report" "-EDefault environment" "C:\example\example.xml"`

Comment: thanks, but not working for me.I tried to run just runas /user:Administrator... command in cmd and it is aksing for password so maybe thats why? But I am wondering why there is problem at all, only with soapui test running python script.There is no problem running only python or only soapui tests.

`06:59:16 c:\workspace>runas /user:Administrator "C:\Program 
Files\SmartBear\ReadyAPI-2.5.0\bin\testrunner.bat" "-RProject Report" "- 
EDefault environment" "C:\example\example.xml" 
06:59:16 c:\workspace>exit 1 
06:59:16 Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as 
failure`